# Can't select first object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, couchdb, pouchdb

I can't find a way to select objects at 0 position in array. Basically, I was looking for functionality to get this **`attributes.prices[0].UnitPrice`** done everywhere and couldn't find an answer. My objective is to select price by range from...to using **`UnitPrice`** field. Products contain prices array:

```
prices: [
  {
    ...,
    UnitPrice: 5
  },
  ...
]
```

Tried tried following queries, but it returns error:

```
...
$and: 
[
            { 'attributes.prices': { $in: { UnitPrice: { $gte: price.from } } } },
            { 'attributes.prices': { $in: { UnitPrice: { $lte: price.to } } } }
            // { 'attributes.prices': { $elemMatch: { UnitPrice: { $gte: price.from } } } },
            // { 'attributes.prices': { $elemMatch: { UnitPrice: { $lte: price.to } } } }
]
```

Error: unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type, $allMatch or $all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `attributes.prices.0.UnitPrice`.

Selector example:

```
{
   "selector": {
      "attributes.prices.0.UnitPrice": 1
   }
}
```